# mysql return a value and the number of times its referenced from a mapping table

Tags: mysql

Say I have two tables: cat_collection and cat_mapping

cat_mapping contains three fields; id, collection_id, and post_id

I would like to be able to select all *names* from cat_collection

```
SELECT name FROM cat_collection
```

as well as the number of times they are referenced in cat_mapping

So if cat_collection contained

```
| id |   | name |
  0        cat1
  1        cat2
```

and cat_mapping contained

```
| id |   | collection_id |   | post_id |
  0              1               0
  1              1               1
```

how can I return

```
| name |   | count |
  cat1        0
  cat2        2
```

---

***solution***

```
SELECT cc.name, (

SELECT COUNT( cm.collection_id )
FROM cat_mapping AS cm
WHERE cm.collection_id = cc.id
) AS `count`
FROM cat_collection AS cc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a subquery like this would do it:

```
SELECT cc.name, (SELECT COUNT(cm.id) FROM cat_mapping cm WHERE cm.collection_id = cc.id) AS cnt
FROM cat_collection cc
```

Comment: this returns only the latter of the two category names, and the cumulative count of both.

Comment: There was an extra closing parenthesis in my answer that shouldn't have been there, I've just fixed it so try that code. I've just set up the tables, ran that exact query and got the exact results you asked for in the question :-)

Comment: `COUNT(cm.id)` should be `COUNT(cm.collection_id)`

Comment: @rlemon: both are fine, `COUNT(*)` would also yield the same result, the column is incidental as you're performing a row count